# Error when installing appium through npm in ubuntu

Tags: android, appium

I've been trying to set up appium to run android tests in an ubuntu machine. Here what i did so far:

- Set up JRE and JDK (and set system variables);
- Installed node.js/npm without using *sudo*;
- Installed  Android SDK and an API Level 22 (and set system
  variables);
- Installed Apache Ant (not configured yet);
- installed git (and set name and e-mail on *gitconfig*)

When i ran `npm install -g appium`, here what i got:

> gyp ERR! build error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/andre/node-v0.12.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
>
> gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/andre/node-v0.12.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd /home/andre/node-v0.12.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.1
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> gyp ERR! build error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/andre/node-v0.12.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
>
> gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/andre/node-v0.12.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>   gyp ERR! cwd /home/andre/node-v0.12.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.1
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.0.1
>
> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.0.1
>
> npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
>
> npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
>
> npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
>
> npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
>
> npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
>
> npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/vojtajina/traceur-compiler Cloning into bare repository '/home/andre/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-vojtajina-traceur-compiler-f4c43c65'...
>
> npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/vojtajina/traceur-compiler fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
>
> npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/vojtajina/traceur-compiler github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=Refused connection
>
> npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
>
> npm ERR! argv "/home/andre/node-v0.12.1-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/andre/node-v0.12.1-linux-x64/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium"
>
> npm ERR! node v0.12.1
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
>
> npm ERR! code 128
>
> npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/home/andre/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/vojtajina/traceur-compiler /home/andre/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-vojtajina-traceur-compiler-f4c43c65
>
> npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/home/andre/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-vojtajina-traceur-compiler-f4c43c65'...
>
> npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
>
> npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=Refused connection
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>
> npm ERR!     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     /home/andre/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Since i'm in a enterprise network, i'm behind a proxy. So i was unable to use git.

Using the commands below, i was able to clone folders using https instead http.

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```